Last four digits in hash must be the same
I have a coding challange where I need the last four characters in a hash to be the same characters.
As a start I have a word and then i must add the suffix to give me the hash with the four characters at the end.
The suffix must be utf-8 and no longer than 1024, this is the best i could come up with:
import hashlib

def find_hash_flag(word):

  for i in range(1000023):
    new_word = word + chr(i)  # Append a character with ASCII value i
    hashed = hashlib.sha256(new_word.encode()).hexdigest()
    if hashed[-4:] == "eeee":
      print(hashed)
      return new_word
  return None

word = "orthosemidin"
modified_word = find_hash_flag(word)


if modified_word:
  print(modified_word)
else:
  print("you failed misereably")

However this makes the characters not encodeable in utf-8
  File "D:\x\x\x\lvl15.py", line 14, in <module>
    modified_word = find_hash_flag(word)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\x\x\x\lvl15.py", line 7, in find_hash_flag
    hashed = hashlib.sha256(new_word.encode()).hexdigest()
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 12: surrogates not allowe


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what you need help with. Maybe you want to ask something like "How do I ignore characters that can't be encoded in UTF-8?", like AKX answered. For tips, see [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify. See also How to ask and answer homework questions. (Even if this isn't homework per se, some of the same advice applies, like, don't ask about your assignment, instead ask about a problem you're stuck on when trying to do the assignment yourself.)

Four same or four "e", which is it?

The Unicode range U+D800 - U+DFFF is reserved for UTF-16 surrogates. You can skip those values, although theoretically only 264 letters (4x a-z) should produce a 164 (4 hex) pattern multiple times.  Below tries 1- to 8-letter suffixes and always found the desired pattern in 3-4 letters added:
import hashlib
import itertools
import string

def find_hash_flag(word):
    for i in range(8):
        for p in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=i+1):
            new_word = f"{word}-{''.join(p)}"
            hashed = hashlib.sha256(new_word.encode()).hexdigest()
            if hashed[-4:] == 'eeee':
                return hashed, new_word
    return None

words = '''\
orthosemidin
limit
wretched
demonic
rhetorical
suspect
jog
spring
lucky
awful
'''.splitlines()

for word in words:
    print(*find_hash_flag(word))

Output:
a3c6f00cc76bcbd2f91eabbc613b0f102a64bbccbc1c3c9f4e7bf2ef790eeeee orthosemidin-cfjn
980be083995c817fffb2c401352725c6a54b6cf5a6c4b9e41d03208c76fceeee limit-duuz
649d66c98d73050dd63cb88c31839c56422883db19636349b45d149bae23eeee wretched-esxl
c1981a6ac259e5f50afb4f5733465f94935f06588a7f09eab571b251d385eeee demonic-djut
4f0eda31dd293fd5565298a4f4a676665939c01f6062b285203989b80ff1eeee rhetorical-bjlo
9625b347ca722a00b0a6818e5cd086aed0512b885ecf28316f285f8330f9eeee suspect-dts
be93163f9e8ed048d576897703054dd7f23c4c8cae0689b3934fed1fc941eeee jog-aouo
d90e18b98ef75359e21347cfbd520e86215d7008f866a2f40106beee84f2eeee spring-aebt
61ae9e47ae280eb3395ef15e05cdbc8b32efaa99cc0d809743c0d0afcc45eeee lucky-zoy
d227cbe8703db6355a5deaa4ba6427b468c968f23c784bc6bf91ba70be2deeee awful-dhpw


That particular character, and certain others, aren't encodable in UTF-8. Just skip over them.
for i in range(1000023):
    try:
        new_word = word + chr(i)  # Append a character with ASCII value i
        hashed = hashlib.sha256(new_word.encode()).hexdigest()
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        continue
    # ...

